# How to send local variables via post

Tags: c#, html, razor

Via a hidden `input field` I want to send a value from **Site 1** to **Site 2**.
But at **Site 2** it says the value is `null`.

I guess this is because it is local value. But it has to be local and I'm not sure.

Here is my code where I declare the value (page 1):

```
string stringproductid = Request.QueryString["id"].tostring();
int productid = stringproductid.AsInt();
```

Here I send it via a hidden field inside a form (page 1):

```
<input type="hidden" id="@productid" value="@productid" name="@productid">
```

Here I try to receive it (at page 2):

```
string idstring = Request.Form["productid"].ToString(); //error
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be `name="productid"` . The `@` you're using there is making Razor put the *value* of productID into that attribute. So if you look at your raw generated HTML it is going to be something like `name="346"`.

That belongs in the "value" attribute, which you did correctly, but what you need to be putting in the "name" is the name of the field, so that the browser posts it back correctly with that field name. :-)

Answer (score 0):

On your 2nd page, you should use

```
string idstring = Request.Form["@productid"].ToString(); //error
```

On a side note, both `Request.QueryString[]` and `Request.Form[]` are always strings, so you don't need to include the `.ToString()`.  I understand it may be defensive coding, but you are just adding CPU cycles. They add up over time.